# Package for tmpwatch

Tags: packaging, cleanup, tmp

I have a server application which runs on redhat and SuSE. It should run on ubuntu servers, too.

The application uses the executable [tmpwatch](http://linux.die.net/man/8/tmpwatch)

There seems to be no package for it in ubuntu.

And I don't understand the meaning of this empty page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tmpwatch

What can I do to make tmpwatch available in ubuntu?

Hint: I know that tmpwatch could be replaced by a script doing `find ... -mtime XX -print0| xargs -r0 rm -rf` but I would like to re-use and not re-invent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on feedback on this question the only way to install `tmpwatch` is to build it from source

First download this source file

```
wget https://fedorahosted.org/releases/t/m/tmpwatch/tmpwatch-2.11.tar.bz2
```

Now extract it

```
tar xjf tmpwatch-2.11.tar.bz2
```

Now enter its directory

```
cd tmpwatch-2.11
```

Now we can build it

```
./configure
make
```

Now install it

```
sudo make install
```

You can now find its .bin file in `/usr/local/sbin`.

Tested Xubuntu 15.10

Comment: Sorry, no: `root@aptguettler:~# dpkg -L tmpreaper| grep bin`:  only /usr/sbin/tmpreaper

Comment: `tmpwatch` is a command you run once the package `tmpreaper`, there is not a `tmpwatch` package, it is part of `tmpreaper`

Comment: I need the executable `tmpwatch`. It is not in the package `tmpreaper`

Comment: `tmpreaper` is the executable , `tmpwatch` is a command called by it. Every thing I find about `tmpwatch` on Ubuntu says `install tmpreaper` There is no `tmpwatch` package for Ubuntu. If that wont work for you, you will have to build the source from here https://fedorahosted.org/tmpwatch/wiki/TmpwatchDownloads

Comment: I installed tmpreaper. AFAIK this package does not install a command called tmpwatch. Look at the `dpkg -L` output in a previous comment. How can tmpreaper call a command that is not installed?

Comment: According to this link it does, however I did try it and you are right, it is not there, seems you will need to build from source, can you do that? http://thelinuxfaq.com/100-how-to-use-tmpwatch-command-in-linux

Comment: No, I can't build from source.

Comment: Do you mean you can't do it or it is not an option? Would you like an answer on it if I can get it to build?

Comment: Ok I managed to install it from source, you will find it at `/usr/local/sbin`, I will make you an answer